# Ninject selecting unexpected constructor

Tags: c#, ninject

Initially I was using the binding `Bind<BlockingCollection<ICommand>>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();` to bind constructor parameters of type `BlockingCollection<ICommand>` to a singleton instance and it was working as expected *(selecting the default constructor)* with no binding errors. I've since done some refactoring and Ninject is no longer selecting the default parameterless constructor as I'm expecting.

`ICommand` is an interface I've defined and `BlockingCollection<T>` is a framework class.

**Constructors** `BlockingCollection<T>`

```
public BlockingCollection() : this(new ConcurrentQueue<T>()){}

public BlockingCollection(int boundedCapacity){}

public BlockingCollection(IProducerConsumerCollection<T> collection, int boundedCapacity){}

public BlockingCollection(IProducerConsumerCollection<T> collection){}
```

**Binding Error**

> Ninject.ActivationException:
>
> Error activating IProducerConsumerCollection{ICommand}
>
> No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
>   Activation path:
>   5) Injection of dependency IProducerConsumerCollection{ICommand} into
>   parameter collection of constructor of type BlockingCollection{ICommand}

**Ninject Constructor Selection Rules**

> The primary DI pattern is Constructor Injection. When activating an
>   instance of a type Ninject will choose one of the type’s constructors
>   to use by applying the following rules in order:-
>
> 1. If a constructor has an [Inject] attribute, it is used (but if you apply the attribute to more than one, Ninject will throw a
>      NotSupportedException at runtime upon detection).
> 2. If no constructors have an [Inject] attribute, Ninject will select the one with the most parameters that Ninject understands how to
>      resolve.
> 3. If no constructors are defined, Ninject will select the default parameterless constructor (assuming there is one).

#2 says *"the most parameters that Ninject understands how to resolve."*, so I'm expecting the default constructor to be selected.

To force the selection of the default parameterless constructor I can use `ToConstructor`, `ToMethod` or `WithConstructorArgument` but I'd like to understand why Ninject did not select the default constructor.

Comment: this is a good question why it's not selecting the best constructor. your best option right now would be to download the Ninject source, build a debug version and debug your app against it, stepping through the code, specifically `StandardConstructorScorer`